# Sort in property grid

Tags: c#, collections, propertygrid

My `Propertygrid` sorted by the A - B.

One of the properties is a `Collection` with expander - I did it using this site: **[Customized display of collection data in a PropertyGrid](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4448/Customized-display-of-collection-data-in-a-Propert)**

I want that if i have in the collection (let's say string) b,a. in the expander is also will be b,a (Now it display a,b).

My question is how to cancel the sorting from the expander of the collection **only**, if possible.

Comment: Can you show us code how you are adding `b` and `a` values? The `IList` they are being added to isn't a sorted list so they should appear in the order they are added.

Comment: They appear in the order they are added in the collection editor, but my property grid define as `CategorizedAlphabetical` so when I expand the list I see them sorted, @Bob.

Comment: I don't think it's possible, if you choose A-Z sorting, all grid items and sub items are sorted by name.

Comment: @SimonMourier. Put your comment as an answer, I also could not find any option to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible, if you choose A-Z sorting, all grid items and sub items are sorted by name.